# HTML5: article inside article?

Tags: html

If we have a list of blog posts, like in this case: http://www.gamempire.it/news
I think that every post could be an `<article>`, but the title of the page ("Novità"), that could be an `<h1>`, is the semantic title of what? A section?

So, i don't know if it's better to do in this way:

```
<section>
  <h1>Novità</h1>
  <article>...</article>
  <article>...</article>
  <article>...</article>
</section>
```

or:

```
<article>
  <h1>Novità</h1>
  <article>...</article>
  <article>...</article>
  <article>...</article>
</article>
```

Answer (score 14):

As far as specs go `<article>` is a [sectioning content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#sectioning-content-0) and as such, [accepts any flow, sectioning and palpable content (except `<main>`)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element), including other `<article>`s.

As far as semantic goes, it depends: articles are independent, self-contained compositions, that can contain other articles as long as those are also independent, self-contained compositions that at the same time are part of the main composition.

> When article elements are **nested**, the inner article elements represent **articles** that **are** in principle **related to** the contents of **the outer article**. For instance, a blog entry on a site that accepts user-submitted comments could represent the comments as article elements nested within the article element for the blog entry.

Answer (score 12):

Your first method is definitely better. You should put your `article`s in a `section`.

---

Check out these two posts on [htlm5doctor](http://html5doctor.com/):

1. [Section](http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/)

> The section element represents a generic document or application section…The section element is not a generic container element. When an element is needed only for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead. A general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the element’s contents would be listed explicitly in the document’s outline.

2. [Article](http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/)

> The article element represents a component of a page that consists of a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is intended to be independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

Comment: but if I put everything in a <section>, what is the title of the <main> (so of the entire page)?

Comment: I think section + article makes sense only when section has a dedicated heading. Otherwise div + article is better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can nested `<article>` as child of `<article>`

See the reference 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is:

```
<section>
  <article>...</article>
  <article>...</article>
  <article>...</article>
</section>
```

Because `<section>` means a piece of your web that can contains the content of your site, and `<article>` is a piece of content.